# woocommerce generate producer-orderlists

Tags: woocommerce, vendors

For a certain webshop, products are made by three different producers. Orders placed by users have to be ordered at these vendors. I'm looking for a add-on which which is capable making producer-orderlists based on the woocommerce orders which the webshop then can send to the producers. I already build in producer support for woocommerce items. There are some specific requirements (such as aggregation) which i can edit myself.

I looked around but find it hard to believe, no such solution is available.

It's different from dropshipping because the producer does not directly send to the customer. These plugins do not suit since they are transparant to the user, offer backend logins for the producers and so on.

Any suggestions?